# Как узнать, какой код ошибки возвращает браузер?

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Есть сайт на Codeignither. Хочу сделать страницу 404.
Для начала как увидеть, какой код возвращает браузер? В массиве `$_SERVER[REDIRECT_STATUS]`?

Если да, то как через `Codeignither` передать заголовок ошибки 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заголовок 404 передается так:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

В кодигнайтере в документации есть [такая](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/general/errors.html) статья. Возможно, Вам поможет.